# check data against array and display next element with jquery mobile function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

I am in need of guidance with comparing items in an array with an item in an html page. First off, I have an array populated with various elements that I need to display. My goal is to get the current content within the title of the currently displayed html page (or some other div that I am displaying) and compare it with each element in the array. Once the match is found I want to display the content of the next index in the html page. This function should execute when a "next" button is clicked. If anyone could help with this I would appreciate it!

Here is what the array is populated with:

```
var item = {title: displayTitle, link: linkUrl, infoDescription: infoDisplay, Date: new Date(eventDate), Region: region,}
```

Here is the page along with the button I would like to call the function:

```
<div data-role="page" id="eventPage"> <!-- Start Event Page -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
            <h1>Mobile</h1>
            <a href="#" onclick="next_event()" target="_blank" data-role="button" class="next"  data-icon="forward" data-iconpos="notext">Next</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="page-title"></div>
        <div id="page-date"></div>
        <div id="page-content"></div>
    </div> 

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed"></div>
</div><!-- End eventPage -->
```

Here is the function which I created to test the idea. Right now, the function just displays every title in the array. I don't want to append the data, I want to replace it. Maybe replaceWith?

```
function next_event() {
    $.each(data, function(i,item){ // notice the item


    $('#page-title').append(item.title);


});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the text of you DOM-nodes only. First of all you have to cache nodes to prevent selecting them each time the button is being clicked.

```
var nodes = {
    title: $('#page-title'),
    date: $('#page-date'),
    content: $('#page-content'),
};
```

Also you may cache the index of currently selected item:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
```

And each time you the button is pressed - the counter should be incremented and text of nodes is changed:

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex >= data.length) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
    nodes.title.text(data[currentIndex].title);
    nodes.date.text(data[currentIndex].date);
    nodes.content.text(data[currentIndex].infoDescription);
});
```

See demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFrDk/2/).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, the jsfiddle is exactly what I was looking for! However, I placed it in my code and tested with no luck. I declared var data = [] outside of any function so I am not sure what the problem is. Any suggestions?

Comment: This was all that showed up: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Also, that error came up before I executed the button click. When I clicked the next button nothing came up in the console.

Comment: Did you include jQuery? could you create a jsfiddle and post as much of your code as you can?

Comment: 1. include jQuery (left top corner of jsFiddle page)
2. what about html? would be great to see it also

Comment: Kiril, I discovered I was not populating the page with the correct Array. I rewrote my code and implemented yours. It worked perfectly, thank you!